# How to test the proportional odds assumption for ordinal regression?

Tags: r, regression, assumptions, ordered-logit

I am trying to test the assumption of proportional odds in order to carry out ordinal logistic regression. I am using R, but can't seem to find an efficient way to do this. I have looked into the graphical method described here: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/ , but I have 21 independent variables so am anticipating that the graphical method would take a long time. I understand that another potential method is to use the VGAM package to examine a model *with* equal slopes and then *without* equal slopes (and compare the results).

Is there a specific advantage to a particular method? Is it advisable to test the assumption in R using either of the above methods, rather use different statistical software that has ready-made tests for this, e.g. SPSS?

Also - would you test this assumption with every candidate model, or just with your first or final model? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't find formal methods so helpful and prefer partial residual plots or comparing with binary logistic regression for a few well-chosen Y cutpoints.  More details in http://fharrellc.com/doc/rms

Comment: Having 21 predictors is quite a lot unless you have hundreds of observations.

Comment: Hi @mdewey, I have already cut down from >100 predictors. I have ~2000 observations. So hopefully it should be OK

Comment: Thank you @FrankHarrell, I followed the suggested measures in the end.

Comment: Sorry my comment had an incorrect link.  It should be fharrell.com/doc/rms.pdf .  And note that upvoting is the best way to give a positive response.  And make sure when you whittled down the number of predictors you did not make use of Y to do so.

Comment: i think the above link is now broken. This one seems now to be the right one https://www.fharrell.com/post/impactpo/index.html#simulation-study-of-effect-of-adjusting-for-a-highly-non-po-covariate